# Parse Array of JSON Objects using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jsonp

Having trouble parsing an array of JSON objects using JavaScript. My PHP file gets database info such as this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => holly
            [text] => Text 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Becky
            [text] => Text 2
        )
)
```

which I then run it through json_encode( to get this:

```
"[\r\n   {\r\n      \"id\":\"1\",\r\n      \"name\":\"holly\",\r\n          
\"text\":\"Text 1\"\r\n   },\r\n   {\r\n      \"id\":\"2\",\r\n      
\"name\":\"Becky\",\r\n      \"tet\":\"Text 2\"\r\n   }\r\n]"
```

This data gets called via a JavaScript function from here: http://oscargodson.com/posts/unmasking-jsonp.html

```
JSONP( url, function(json){console.log(json)});
```

The callback doesn't return anything I can parse, I just get [Object Object] if I do console.log(json). I am getting results from PHP because the Sources tab in Chrome's web developer shows the php file and the jsonified text. I just can't figure out how to send it to JavaScript for parsing.

I've read tons of 'duplicate' questions and many say use JSON.stringify() but I don't get any results.

Is the error with my PHP or I'm just not using JavaScript properly? Please help.

Comment: you source data is json, why you encoding json to json? If you set `Content-type:application/json` if I don't wrong, and set type in ajax function jQuery json. You can get data.your_data in callback function first parameters

Comment: sorry, edited the post with the correct PHP print_r()

Comment: also, no jQuery. Using JavaScript only

Comment: use JSON.parseJSON(result);

Comment: JSON.parse(result) gives an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
This means the result is already an object as I understand it.

Comment: `JSONP( url, function(){json}); ` you forgot first param `function(json) { console.log(json)}` in JSONP function

Comment: ah, good catch. I edited the post with the correct code. Thank you.

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(json[0])`?

Comment: console.log(json[0]) results in undefined

Comment: It sounds like the data is not getting passed and an empty object is being returned instead. Are you sure the URL you're passing is correct/valid?

Comment: That's where I'm confused. PHP is passing the JSONified array to the browser. I can see the results under Chrome's Source tab but I can can't programmatically access these results via JavaScript. I tried using a for loop and forEach in JS but nothing works to access the data.

Comment: How are they being passed to the browser? You should be outputting them to a unique URL containing no other data besides the JSON.

Comment: php file is being called in the JSONP() function. The callback should return the results to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The JSONP() function from the article won't work with data from the database but will if the same data is hard-coded. Weird.

```
var result =  [
    {"id":"1","name":"holly","text":"Text 1"},    
    {"id":"2","name":"Becky","text":"Text 2"}
];

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

}
```

weird. Not sure why that function doesn't return as expected but I guess that's why jQuery has $.getJSON() so we don't have to go through all of this every time.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run your data through plain

```
json_encode($data)
```

But please beware any other arguments passed to this call - because in the string that you posted (the result of the JSON encode function) - you had it **pretty printed**.
Which is probably the main reason your JSONP calls to such resource fail - the data is pretty-printed - when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "callback/yourcallback.php", //at the end echo json_encode($array);
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: { paramname: paramvalue},
    type: "POST"
})
.done(function( data )
{
    var response=$.parseJSON(data);
      console.log(response);
});
```